# What is a monotonic query operator?

Tags: database

What is a monotonic query operator in the context of stream databases?

To phrase my question differently: What makes a query operator monotonic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query operator is monotonic if its result contains the result at any earlier time.

Monotonicity means that the result include earlier results, and only "add" to them.

Comment: This explanation is incomplete and inaccurate. A [monotonic query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_query) must include all earlier results **when new information is added to the database**. However, it is possible that a monotonic query discards earlier results if information from the database is removed or updated. Thus, monotonicity means that *if information in the database increases*, then the query result either stays the same or increases. The definition implies nothing if information is updated or deleted.